# Word for something that is either very easy or impossible

Tags: single-word-requests

If projects, people or problems are polarized so that they are either very easy or impossible, is there an appropriate word to describe the polarization towards the two extremes?

For example, if I succeed it will never be difficult but very easy and still I don't often succeed and it's unrelated to how much effort I make.

More precise, I'm practicing solving problems and I either answer correctly with almost no effort or it is impossible when it is not easy.

Similarly, there are projects, people, relations and arrangements that are either easy or impossible and even you try very hard and work very hard it is still impossible if it is not very easy.

The best word I can think of is "polarization" but it is not a common word to use about what I typically mean here.

Comment: ‘If’ seems to be the operative word here.
Polarization is the process of defining, or rather, creating poles; not choosing between or moving towards them.
‘Extremities’ are physical objects, such as hands or walls; degrees of difficulty, like politics, have ‘extremes’ which are indeed almost synonymous with ‘poles’, both being created or defined by the process of ‘polarisation’.
Sadly that doesn’t make the question ‘easy’, let alone ‘very easy.’
The question seems ‘impossible’ to me on several levels and I don’t think that or anything else will make it ‘(very) easy’ for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entities in question are ***extremities*** (in the context of level of difficulty).

> The problems I tried out today were ***extremities*** in terms of difficulty
>   - either I could solve them very easily or not at all.

ODO:

> **[extremity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extremity)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** The furthest point or limit of something:
>
> ‘Fundamentally, there is little to choose between the extremities of
>   right and left in politics.’